# Is it possible to get a team name of a user who authored a pull request

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-rest-api

I am looking for a way to get a team name of a user that authored a pull request and can't seem to find way to get this information.  Found a few examples that use graph to get the memberships but I don't know how to map those to team names. I have build validations that trigger Sonarqube scan pipeline - The goal is to skip pr decorations for certain teams.

I am getting the pr data using _apis/git/pullrequests/${pullrequestid}?api-version=6.0 - this returns me the user id, their name and the descriptor but how do I know find out which team they're on?

Comment: Does the following REST API work for you? Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you can try to use the "user descriptor" to list all groups by using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#all-groups-for-a-user):

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/graph/Memberships/{user Descriptor}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

It will return all groups for the user. And then you could match the group descriptor to get the group name.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups/{groupDescriptor}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

Please check if it meets your requirements.

12.16 UPDATE:

For Azure DevOps Sever 2020, you could try to use descriptor to read identities [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to list the users' member of.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/identities?descriptors={descriptors}&queryMembership=expanded&api-version=6.0
```

And then use the groups' descriptors to check the groups' displayname.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this possible with Azure Devops Server 2020?

Comment: @Redline1111 I have updated the answer for Azure DevOps Server 2020. Please have a look.